# Decision tree / boosting tree in Tensorflow?

Tags: boosting, tensorflow

When I was looking for some way to break the bottleneck of memory limitation in xgboost, I found there are some boosting tree algorithm that is implemented in Tensorflow such as [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesClassifier). I have some questions about the implementation of boosting tree in Tensorflow:

1. Does the implementation support mini-batch optimization? If so, how is the mini-batch optimization realized?
2. Why bother to use Tensorflow to implement a boosting tree algorithm? The tree-construction process is not differentiable as far as I know, due to the discontinuity at the splitting boundary, therefore the auto-differentiation is only useful for calculating the gradient and hessian for loss function, but these are usually very simple analytical function.
3. Is there some mid-ground between a fully differentiable model and a tree, so that we can still enjoy the advantages from stochastic gradient descent and interpretability of a tree model?